# IIS and SQL Server Windows authentication in a django application

Tags: iis, sql-server, django, windows-authentication

I am trying to run a django website which connects to a SQL Server, using IIS with Windows authentication.

IIS server and SQL server are on different machines under the same domain i.e., ***iis_machine.example.com*** and ***sql_machine.example.com***

**What I'm trying to achieve**:

1. Impersonate the remote user accessing the django website hosted on IIS, so his Windows credentials are passed to SQL Server for authentication.

**What I tried so far**:

1. Added this to my web.config file for impersonation

   `<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
   </system.web>`
2. Enabled Windows authentication and set up Application Pool (***django_web***) for
   django website as shown below

   [This is what my Authentication for django website looks like in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xzlo.png)

   [This is what my Application Pool for django website looks like in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gCJA.png)
3. Added ***IIS APPPOOL\django_web*** to SQL Server ***Security\Logins***

**Result**:

1. When I access the django website, IIS prompts the user for his
   Windows credentials and I can successfully login
2. If user tries to access SQL Server after logging in

   *Case a*. IIS, SQL Server are on the different machines: SQL server authentication fails with
   "***Login failed for user 'domain\MACHINENAME$***'

   *Case b*. IIS, SQL Server are on the same machine, SQL server authentication is successful but authentication credentials used are ***IIS APPPOOL\django_web*** not ***domain\remote_user***

I understand that there is some Kerberos trickery involved with this setup. Unfortunately, I'm only a programmer and not very familiar with how Kerberos works. If someone experienced in this domain, could shed some light on how this setup would work, that'd be really appreciated. Thanks!

I am using:

- IIS 10
- SQL Server 2014
- django 2.0.7
- Python 3.6.5
- Windows 8/10

Comment: Impersonation and delegation was the legacy people cannot easily escape. But modern SQL Server release (such as 2022) added OAuth/Entra support, which is the preferred approach https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/azure-ad-authentication-sql-server-setup-tutorial?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the `django_web` account to be allowed to delegate to the SQL server. I guess since this is `IIS APPPOOL\django_web` you actually need to configure it on the machine  account in Active Directory. Alternatively you can create a custom service account for it instead.

Comment: Thanks, so I managed to setup a custom service account in the AD as domain\svc_account and added it to SQL server logins. So any user who accesses sql server from django website is authorized as domain\svc_account now. But how can I achieve impersonation? Is there something I need to do inside django app itself?

Comment: I couldn't say about Django specifically. If the SQL library understands Windows auth it probably understands delegation (big assumption though). You need to explicitly configure delegation on the service account. Maybe this is helpful: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlupdates/2014/12/05/sql-server-kerberos-and-spn-quick-reference/

Comment: I posted a follow up question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/928911/kerberos-double-hop-delegation-from-iis-to-sql-server-using-django) after taking your suggestions into acccount? Could you please take a look?