# Kerberos Double Hop Delegation from IIS to SQL server (using django)

Tags: iis, sql-server, kerberos, django, delegation

I need to pass the credentials (Integrated Windows Authentication) from a django website on IIS onto a backend SQL server so that it runs under the proper user context.

**This is how my setup looks so far**:

1. Running SQL Server on `sql_sever.domain.com` under a service account `domain\svc_sqlserver`
2. Running Django website on `app_server.domain.com` using IIS under a service account `domain\svc_appserver` with Windows authentication and ASP.Net Impersonation (Providers is set to `Negotiate:Kerberos -> Negotiate -> NTLM` ) with `useAppPoolCredentials=True`
3. Connecting to SQL server from django using Windows authentication by setting `Trusted_Connection=yes` in the connection
4. Configured SPNs for Kerberos authentication both for `domain\svc_sqlserver` and `domain\svc_appserver` as follows:

   ```
   setspn -a HTTP/app_server                          domain\svc_appserver
   setspn -a HTTP/app_server.domain.com               domain\svc_appserver
   setspn -a MSSQLSvc/sql_server.domain.com:PORT      domain\svc_sqlserver
   setspn -a MSSQLSvc/sql_server.domain.com:INSTANCE  domain\svc_sqlserver
   setspn -a MSSQLSvc/sql_server.domain.com           domain\svc_sqlserver
   ```
5. Trusted both `svc_sqlserver` and `svc_appserver` for delegation to `MSSQLSvc` services and additionally for `domain\svc_appserver` I added `HTTP` services too (from the above list)

**Result**:

1. Kerberos authentication works on SQL Server. Confirmed by looking at [auth scheme of connected users](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1218445-9-1.aspx)
2. Kerberos authentication works on Django website. Confirmed by inspecting `WWW-Authenticate` response header and `Authorization` request header (`Negotiate` is being correctly used)
3. Sql server runs only under the context of `domain\svc_appserver` when it should be running under `domain\remote_user`

I've been working on this for more than a week now but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to pass authenticated user's context from IIS to SQL Server. I went through hundreds of links I found online and I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Is there anything else that I'm missing? Is there any way in Django to set the user's context before establishing connection to database? If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate. Thanks!

**I'm using**:

- django 2.0.7
- [django-pyodbc-azure](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure)
- Python 3.6.5
- IIS 10, SQL Server 2014

Comment: DelegConfig can be used to validate the KCD configuration. https://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2009/06/delegconfig-v2-beta-delegation-kerberos-configuration-tool . Also, "Negotiate" in the WWW-Authenticate header does not confirm that a Kerberos token is used.  https://serverfault.com/a/440050/20701 . If it's NTLM, it isn't going to work.

Comment: @GregAskew I set Provider to only `Negotiate:Kerberos` too and it works. So i'm pretty sure Kerberos is working. However, I got the answer for the same question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52120859/kerberos-double-hop-delegation-from-iis-to-sql-server-using-django). Thanks!